# Output voltage of PIR sensor

Tags: arduino-mega

[image][image]

Case 1
I am measuring output voltage of PIR sensor, I am getting 3.3v

Case 2
I have connected a resistor and a led to output of PIR sensor. Now when I measure voltage at the output pin of the sensor, I am getting 2.04v only.

In case 2 as the output voltage is dropped, it is not able to trigger a high state to arduino pin.

Where am I going wrong? What shall I change?

Comment: I believe you have to remember that the LED itself has a voltage drop of about 1.7V, so 3.3 - 1.7 = @1.6V.  Plus the voltage drop over your resistor depending upon the size it is.  So that voltage drop should be expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PIR can’t provide enough current to drive the led. The maximum current for the BIS0001 is 10mA.

Either increase the resistor value, and accept that the led is less bright.

Or use a transistor to drive the led.

Or connect the led to an Arduino pin and turn the led on by code, based on the input pin connected to the PIR